# How to efficiently publish in Sitecore 6.4 items in non-final workflow states?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

While items that have reached a final workflow state can be easily published to the WEB database using, for example, a scheduled task that calls PublishManager.PublishSmart, I would like to be able to publish the latest version of all items that are in any workflow state to a different publishing target (for internal preview), essentially bypassing workflow.

What would you recommend to be the most **efficient** way to perform this, keeping in mind that this needs to happen a few times a day on a **schedule** and **not** every time an item is modified and/or changes workflow state?

How would that recommendation change if I changed the requirement by saying that only items that are in **some** (**final** and/or **not final**) specific workflow state (e.g. *pending approval* and *approved*) need to be published to the preview publishing target on a schedule?

Answer (score 2):

See this blog post by Alex Shyba: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/09/publish-to-pre-production-web-database.html.  That workflow provider plus a standard publish agent should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I had read the Shiba trilogy on this topic. The 2010 solution works only through actions, i.e. when an item moves from one workflow state to another one that has the flag to publish on the preview DB turned on. The 2009 post seems more like the answer to my first requirement, but, as explained in the 2010 post, it has drawbacks when someone does a site smart publish.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, publishes will work as expected to preview or production. The flag is only there to designate "at this stage we can publish this item to preview" to allow for multiple steps in between in the workflow - "semi-final" could be the first or nth step. I think there is a step there to auto-publish to QA as well but normal publish should work as you are expecting too.

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to configure a site that points at the Master database.  See this stackoverflow answer on setting up a preview site: [Preview site for Sitecore editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408400/preview-site-for-sitecore-editors)

Comment: Tried that. "Live sites" though are supposed to have cache turned off (makes sense, right) and this means that the PREVIEW site is unacceptably slow for the client. So we had to scrap this approach which was our primary choice.

Answer (score 1):

Publish in the context of a site (as defined in web.config under `<sites>`) that has `enableworkflows=false`.

Untested, but something like:

```
using (new SiteContextSwitcher(SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext("system"))) // workflows not enabled
        {
            var options = new PublishOptions(Context.ContentDatabase, Factory.GetDatabase("web"), PublishMode.Smart, null, DateTime.Now);
            options.PublishingTargets.Clear();
            options.PublishingTargets.Add("internal preview");
            new Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher(options).Publish();
        }
```

[See this answer to the opposite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285284/678453)!

Comment: Never thought about skinning this cat this particular way. Good suggestion!